# angular 7 api not getting called

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call API but i think something is wrong,

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export class Message {
    constructor(public text: any, public sentBy: any) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public sendMessage(message) {
        const usertext = new Message(message, 'user');
        console.log("message send",usertext);
       return this.http
            .post<any>(`http://locahost:3000/api/text_query`, usertext)
            .pipe(
                map(response => {
                    return response;
                })
            );
    }

}
```

Not getting any logs in `Network tab` of chrome.
I am using angular 7.0.1 and typescript: 3.1.3
Here is my app component file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ChatService} fom './chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {}

  sendMessage() {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message).subscribe(res=>{
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

the service is properly added in app.module.ts file

Comment: Are you subscribing to `sendMessage` at some place in the app?

Comment: no, i am calling from app component and data is coming here, whatever i want to send

Comment: So inject your service in AppComponent and subscribe to sendMessage of service in appComponent class.

Comment: Please include the code from your AppComponent showing how you've injected the ChatService into the component and how you've invoked the sendMessage method.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you inject this service `ChatService` in your component.

`ChatService` should be registered as providers to the app module or where it's used and then you have to subscribing to `sendMessage` at in the component where service is injected.

Make sure your service is registered in list of providers at app.module or has the `Injectable` declaration at top:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

a common example of service in angular 7 is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class ChatService{

  constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Methods exposed by the `HttpClient` generally return a Cold Observable. It would essentially mean that these methods won't make any API call unless the Observables that they return are `subscribe`d to.

To fix your issue:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export interface Message {
  public text: any;
  public sentBy: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  public sendMessage(message) {
    const usertext: Message = { text: message, sentBy: 'user' };
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`http://locahost:3000/api/text_query`, usertext);
  }

}
```

And in your Component:

```
...
import { ChatService } from "path-to-chat-service";

@Component({...})
export class ChatComponent {
  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {}

  sendMessage(message) {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(message)
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }

  ...

}
```

---

Helpful Resources:

1. [**Hot vs Cold Observables**](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) - By Ben Lesh(RXJS Lead).
2. [**COLD VS HOT OBSERVABLES**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html) - Thoughtram.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to your observable with .subscribe()

Btw: why'd you map to the same value?

```
       map(response => {
            return response;
        })
```