# express app.delete isn't called and not showing in console code

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have this issue, why this data isn't delete, also there is not showing any message in the console log of the code backend, i think it's a problem with the subscription, but in the example was i see, there are same writing at of mine code, mmmh i hope can resolve this, here is the code:

list-tags.component.html

```
 <!-- Created Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Eliminar</mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <span class="select-item">
                  <button type="button" (click)="deleteTag(row.id)" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                </span>
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

list-tags.components.ts

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { TagsService } from './../../../../services/tags.service';
import { Tag } from './../../../../models/tag';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-tags',
  templateUrl: './list-tags.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-tags.component.css']
})
export class ListTagsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  public displayedColumns: string[]
  public resultsLength: number;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Tag>;

  public tags: Tag[];
  private tagsSub: Subscription;

  constructor(public tagsService: TagsService) {

    this.displayedColumns = ['content', 'created', 'edit', 'delete'];
    this.resultsLength = 0;
    this.tags = [];
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tagsService.getTags();
    this.tagsSub = this.tagsService.getTagsUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((tags: Tag[]) => {
      this.tags = tags;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tags);
      this.resultsLength = this.tags.length;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.tagsSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  editTag(tag: any){
    console.log(tag)
  }

  deleteTag(tagId: string){
    console.log(tagId)
    this.tagsService.deleteTag(tagId);
  }
```

tags.service.ts

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Tag } from './../models/tag';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TagsService {

  deleteTag(tagId: string) {
    this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/api/tags/" + tagId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        const updatedTags = this.tags.filter(tag => tag.id !== tagId);
        this.tags = updatedTags;
        this.tagsUpdated.next([...this.tags]);
      })
  }
```

backend/app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Work = require("./models/work");
const Tag = require("./models/tags");

const app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/QCdb")
.then(() =>{
    console.log('Connected to database');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log("Error to connected database")
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
  });

app.delete("/api/tags/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("here not showing log...")
    try{
        Tag.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json({ message: "Tag deleted!" });
        })
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

I will continue in my search, thank you very much to the people who can give me a light of what is happening in the code.

---

I found something, I discovered that the api works, but, only when I put next (), after displaying the data.

```
app.use("/api/tags", (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        Tag.find().then(documents => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "posts fetched successfully",
                tag: documents
            });
        });
        next();  
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

With this next() method, i try but it catch another error, and can't display the data, later of the delete action, if i remove this next() method, the route.delete() isn't work, and tried to the same issue of the original post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 7 api not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820361/angular-7-api-not-getting-called)

Comment: ooh thanks, but isn't the problem this have these code, here i update the code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this!! finally. the problem is

Here the original get data code.

```
app.use("/api/tags", (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        Tag.find().then(documents => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "posts fetched successfully",
                tag: documents
            });
        });
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

how it's works just, change use, for get.

```
app.get("/api/tags", (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        Tag.find().then(documents => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "posts fetched successfully",
                tag: documents
            });
        });
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

why?, i don't know, supose it's time to read some DOC